# azure log analytics - concat two graphs in log analytics

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-log-analytics

I have two queries: both have similar results. I just want to draw both on one time chart in azure log analytics.

customEvents
| where name startswith "USER_LOGIN" 
| extend responseTime_in_sec = todouble(customMeasurements.responseTime)/1000 
| summarize avg(responseTime_in_sec) by responseTime_in_sec, bin(timestamp, 1h) 
| render timechart

customEvents
| where name startswith "DEPENDENT_SERVICE"
| extend responseTime_in_sec = todouble(customMeasurements.responseTime)/1000 
| summarize avg(responseTime_in_sec) by responseTime_in_sec, bin(timestamp, 1h) 
| render timechart

[image]

Comment: maybe I'm missing something but what about simply this? `customEvents | where name startswith "DEPENDENT_SERVICE" or name startswith "USER_LOGIN" | extend responseTime_in_sec = todouble(customMeasurements.responseTime)/1000 | summarize avg(responseTime_in_sec) by name, responseTime_in_sec, bin(timestamp, 1h) | render timechart`

Comment: Thanks @silent, I literally feel like an idiot. I tried everything like 'let', 'union'; but missed this simple thing.

Comment: so this worked? then I'll make an answer out of it :)

Comment: @silent You can add it as answer to share the useful info to more members.Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, sometimes the solution can be quite easy :)

```
customEvents 
| where name startswith "DEPENDENT_SERVICE" or name startswith "USER_LOGIN" 
| extend responseTime_in_sec = todouble(customMeasurements.responseTime)/1000 
| summarize avg(responseTime_in_sec) by name, responseTime_in_sec, bin(timestamp, 1h) 
| render timechart
```

If the query is more complex than this, often the [union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/unionoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer) operator can help as welll.